# bitcoind has 0 connections

Tags: network

I'm running bitcoind on a remote server (so I can only use the "headless" version). However, the client is not connecting to the bitcoin network. The "getinfo" command shows "connections: 0". I have also been keeping an eye on the blocks folder and there is no change there (when running bitcoin on the local machine, I can see files being created and updated there).

Here's what my bitcoin.conf looks like:

```
daemon=1
server=1
rpcuser=<redacted>
rpcpassword=<redacted>
rpcport=<redacted>
rpctimeout=60
```

Port 8333 is open for UDP traffic in my firewall and I have used an external port scanner to verify that it is open. However, I understand that that's not actually necessary for outgoing connections. I've also checked that my date / time is synchronized (this was suggested in some of the threads that I found on this topic).

What are other possibilities?

Comment: What output do you get from `netstat | grep 8333`?

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin uses TCP. Configure your firewall to open TCP port 8333.